# NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass for assets:precompile on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, devise

An app using devise and omniauth is working well on localhost, but when I deploy it on heroku, I get an error:

```
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile
       rake aborted!
       NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/config/initializers/omniauth.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `instance_eval'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/omniauth-1.2.2/lib/omniauth/builder.rb:6:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `new'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:43:in `build'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `block in build'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `inject'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.4/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/stack.rb:118:in `build'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/engine.rb:498:in `app'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:36:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:300:in `initialize!'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `block in require'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:247:in `require'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:276:in `require_environment!'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.4/lib/rails/application.rb:379:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
       /tmp/build_e711adadeab2d8cb9d37632e4c0ba08b/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.2.2/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:64:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => environment
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app

To git@heroku.com:my-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Here is Gemfile and omniauth files:

```
#Gemfile:
#....
gem 'google-api-client'
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'devise'
#.....


#config/initializers/omniauth.rb

# probably this isn't necessary
if Rails.env.production?
  OmniAuth.config.full_host = 'https://my-app.herokuapp.com'
end

# but it is necessary
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(:google_oauth2, $ga_client['client_id'], $ga_client['client_secret'], 
    { scope: 'userinfo.profile, userinfo.email, analytics', access_type: 'offline', prompt: 'consent' }
  )
end
```

Comment: Line 6 is the 'end', is that the omniauth file you were deploying?

Comment: @RichardAE, it points to `provider(:google_oauth2, .....` line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, $ga_client is nil. You are not defining such an array anywhere in your file and, in case is defined in other place, it's not loaded at the time this initializer is executed.

Try setting the client_id and client_secret with environment variables, as recommended in the docs.

```
provider :google_auth2, ENV['GOOGLE_KEY'], ENV['GOOGLE_SECRET']
```

Comment: but `$ga_client` is defined in `initializers/ga.rb`. hasn't it been executed by the time when omniauth.rb is being executed?

Comment: The stacktrace says it s nil. defining that in other file does not make it available  here

Comment: it's a global variable and it should be visible.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding $ variables. In ruby those are not global variables. Check this for some uses of $ in ruby: http://jimneath.org/2010/01/04/cryptic-ruby-global-variables-and-their-meanings.html

Comment: are you saying that `Variables starting with $ are global,` is false?

Comment: Hmmm it looks Im wrong on the last one. There ARE $ global  variables in ruby, but they are regarded as bad practice - as you could experience yourself! :-) the problem might be the load order of the initializers. Using ENV variables is still the way to go

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71162/discussion-between-dgilperez-and-alexander-supertramp).

Answer (score 0):

The globals variables weren't initialized:

```
# but it is necessary

Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider(:google_oauth2, $ga_client['client_id'], $ga_client['client_secret'], 
    { scope: 'userinfo.profile, userinfo.email, analytics', access_type: 'offline', prompt: 'consent' }
  )
end

# ops $ga_client is nil
```

I discovered it when I replaced the code above with:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :google_oauth2, ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"], ENV["GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET"]
end
```

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same problem. The cause of this problem is that Rails uses a database system called **sqlite3**, Heroku does not use this database. To fix this, go into your **Gemfile** and scroll down until you see something which will look a bit like this

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
end
```

**Note**: If you are using any versions lower than Rails 4.0.0, you will not have this group, simply create it.

Now somewhere at the top of your Gemfile, will be a line which says

```
gem 'sqlite3'
```

Move this line into the **Development, Test Group** This now will only run in development. You can now try creating your Heroku app again by writing

```
$ heroku create
```

Then you may need to migrate your database. Do this by running

```
$ rake db:migrate
```

Now push to Heroku

```
$ heroku push
```

That should work!

Hope I helped ;)

Comment: This has nothing to do with the error and stacktrace